# Rate of growth of ratio of n-th prime to im part of n-th zero of $\zeta(z)$

Tags: prime-number-theorem

Let $P(n)$ be the $n$-th prime, and let $Z(n) = -i (\rho_n - \frac12) $ where $\rho_n $ is the n-th zero of he zeta function (that is, the zero with n-th smallest positive imaginary part).  Let $R(N) = \frac{P(n)}{Z(n)}$.

> What is known about the rate of growth of $R(n)$?

I have a hand-waving argument that says that $R(n)$ should not grow faster than $O(\sqrt{n})$ but numerical results seem to show that it grows slower than that.

In fact, it seems as if $$R(n) = \mbox{O}\left( \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\log(n)\log(\log(n))}\right)$$
but I have no clue how to prove that.

On the other hand, this is near to the guts of the PNT so I would imagine somebody already knows the best bounds for this rate of growth.

Another observation is that for all $1000 < n < 6000$, 
$$
 \left| R(n) - \sqrt[3]n\, \left(0.57 - n\cdot 10^{-5}\right) \right|<0.004
$$
but that has to be spurious since for large $n$ the expression goes negative.

Comment: The $n$-th prime is about $n\log n$.  The $n$-th zero has ordinate about $2\pi n/\log n$.  So $R(n)$ is about $2\pi (\log n)^2$.   Is there a reason for this numerology?

Comment: I guess not.  Although I'm not sure why but your $2\pi$ appears to instead need to be about $\frac18$. How big does $n$ have to be before $R(n) $ becomes greater than $(\log n)^2$?

Comment: @Lucia, I think you mean $(1/(2\pi))n/\log n$. $Z(200,000,001)=81,702,130$, approximately [https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pub/pub081.html], and $P(200,000,001)=4,222,234,763$ [https://primes.utm.edu/nthprime/index.php#nth]

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Yes, division error:  $n\log n/(2\pi n/\log n)  = (\log n)^2/(2\pi)$ indeed.

Comment: @Lucia, I corrected the wrong part of your comment, but, yes, $R(n)$ should be about as you say, $(\log n)^2/(2\pi)$.